# How to get the number of rows returned from a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way that I can get the COUNT(*) of what a query will return? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 // Query
SELECT (*) FROM table LIMIT 10 // Query Count
```

This would actually ignore the limit (
[MySQL COUNT with LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020842/mysql-count-with-limit)). While this might be fine and 'correct' within sql, I need the exact number of rows the query is returning. How would this be done?

Comment: Did you consider `SELECT MIN(COUNT(pk), 10) FROM table WHERE column = 'value'`? (this would obviously *not* work with offsets)

Comment: Use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROW()`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you actually want to accommodate limit, you can use:

```
select count(*) from (SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10) as t
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a more performant way to do the above than executing the subquery on SELECT * ?

Comment: @David542 I cannot tell for sure whether mysql will optimize it or not, but it make sense to select only primary key column instead of `*`